# Bug on save model in DB (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In general, when creating a database according to the scheme, an error pops up in the console that I did not write something correctly in the database. How to solve this?
The circuit itself:

```
let mongoose = require(`mongoose`);
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;


let newOrder = new Schema({
    courses: [
      {
        course: {
          type: Object,
          required: true
        },
        Count: {
          type: Number,
          required: true
        }
      }
    ],
    user: {
      name: String,
      userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: `user`,
        required: true
      }
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
})


module.exports = mongoose.model(`order`, newOrder);
```

User schema:

```
    let mongoose = require(`mongoose`);
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let NewUser = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cart: {
        items: [
            {
                Count: {
                    type: Number,
                    required: true,
                    default: 1
                },
                CourseId: {
                    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: `products`,
                    required: true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
})


// Метод для добавления или увеличения количества продуктов в корзине
NewUser.methods.addToBasket = function (prod){
    let clone = [...this.cart.items];
    
    let idx = clone.findIndex((event)=>{
         return event.CourseId.toString() === prod._id.toString();
    })

    if(idx > -1){
        clone[idx].Count = clone[idx].Count + 1;
    } else {
        clone.push({
            Count: 1,
            CourseId: prod._id
        })
    }

    // Устанавливаем обновленный массив продуктов в корзине пользователя
    this.cart = {items: clone};
    return  this.save();

}

// Метод для удаления или уменьшения количества продуктов в корзине
NewUser.methods.remToBasket = function (id){
    let clone = [...this.cart.items];

    let idx = clone.findIndex((event)=>{
        return event.CourseId.toString() == id.toString();
    });

    if(clone[idx].Count === 1){
        // Фильтром мы перебираем все елементы в нашей 
        // корзине и перезаписываем елементы опять в эту же 
        // корзину только если перебираемый id не равен 
        // id который мы отослали на сервер удалить
        clone = clone.filter((event)=>{

           return event.CourseId.toString() !== id.toString();

        })
        console.log(clone);
    } else { 
        clone[idx].Count--;
    }

    this.cart = {items: clone};
    this.save();
}

NewUser.methods.clearProd = function (){
    this.cart = {items: []}
    return this.save();
}


mongoose.model(`user`, NewUser);
```

And here's how I create it in a router:

```
let {Router} = require(`express`);
let Order = require(`../models/or`);
let router = Router();

// Обычьный get запрос для получения страницы
router.get(`/`, function(req, res){
  res.render(`order.hbs`, {
    order: true
  })
})

// Post запрос присылающий в базу данных заказ пользователя
router.post(`/`, async (req,res)=>{
  let user = await req.user.cart.populate(`cart.items.CourseId`).execPopulate();
     

  let order = new Order({
    user: {
      name: req.user.name,
      userId: req.user
    },
    courses: user
  })


  await order.save();
  await req.user.clearProd();
  
  res.redirect(`/order`);
})


module.exports = router;
```

But the base is not created with such a scheme and an error pops up:

(node:8860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: order validation failed: courses.0.Count: Path `Count` is required., courses.0.course: Path `course` is required.
at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\Хорошо\Desktop\Node.js\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2729:32)
at EmbeddedDocument.invalidate (C:\Users\Хорошо\Desktop\Node.js\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\embedded.js:298:29)
at C:\Users\Хорошо\Desktop\Node.js\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2541:17
at C:\Users\Хорошо\Desktop\Node.js\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1255:9
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
(node:8860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8860) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates, that the `user` variable doesn't contain the properties `courses` requires. You haven't shown what `req.user.cart.populate(`cart.items.CourseId`).execPopulate()` returns, but the error indicates, that the returned value doesn't contain `Count`. Maybe you wrote `count` with a lower-case `c`? Or maybe the property isn't returned at all. Attach a debugger or print `user` to console (`console.log(user)`) if you're unsure.

```
let user = await req.user.cart.populate(`cart.items.CourseId`).execPopulate();

let order = new Order({
  user: {
    name: req.user.name,
    userId: req.user
  },
  //       ↓ Make sure the the object you pass here actually contains "Count"
  courses: user
})
```

Your schema requires courses to be an array of objects with a `course` and `Count` property. The error says that `user` doesn't contain `Count`.

```
courses: [
  {
    course: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    Count: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  }
]
```

As a side note: express doesn't handle `async` functions. This means that any error thrown (as in your example) isn't handled. This is what causes the long error message and warning. To properly catch and handle errors in route handlers, you can use a package like [`express-promise-router`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router) (disclaimer: I maintain this package). It replaces the `Router` from express with one that catches and handles errors properly.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want to transfer the number of courses to the "courses", that is, an array in which there will be `objects`

Then it's worth changing `Object` -> `Array` and `courses: (your path to the array)`

I hope I helped you :)